# Jquery switch between ID's

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm attempting to make a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game.
As the animation finished, I would like to switch the ID's of the players & PC's div's so that they display a different image.

I have tried the following methods so far:

I tried this one both with and without the #, to no success:

```
$('#player').attr('#player','#playerP');
```

I didn't expect this one to work, as I'm trying to use it as a result of an if / else statement, but I thought I would try it anyway:

```
$( "#player" ).click(function() {
        $(this).switchClass( "player", "playerP",);
        });
```

Also tried this one with and without the #:

```
$('#player').removeClass('player').addClass('playerP');
```

I have also tried to use `.toggleClass()`, but to my understanding that is used to turn a single class on and off, so it didn't work for me either (or maybe I used it incorrectly).

I have tried the examples from multiple different questions here on and other other sites (but I can't post that many links, so I can't link them) in different formats while trying to apply it to my code with little success.

My WIP can be found [here](http://www.codecademy.com/javaWhiz66294/codebits/2BKKrK) or on JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5xu3syL3/)

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you switching between ids?

Comment: to switch between classes you can use `$('#player').toggleClass('player playerP');`

Comment: The first argument to `.attr()` should be the name of an attribute, like `id`, `class`, `href`, etc.

Comment: `player` and `playerP` are IDs, not classes. It's usually a bad idea to move IDs around, you should use classs for styling.

Comment: Just tried both `$('id').attr('#player','#playerP');` and `$('#player').toggleClass('player playerP');`, but they didn't work. I could be using them in the wrong context though .-.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this but this is how to swap the id.

```
$("#player").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', 'playerp');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5xu3syL3/1/

As others have already mentioned, it's best to do your styling with classes, not id's.

Comment: Thanks, I've switched over to using classes and managed to get it working :)